# Library not found for -lFirebase after installing XLForm

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, xlform

I have a project in Swift where I use some libraries. When I run on the simulators or on the physical device, it runs perfectly. But by the time I try to archive the project to send it to the store, I receive the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lFirebase
```

The problem is when I use the `XLForm` library, which was the last modification I have done to my `Podfile`.

I am using the `.xcworkspace` since I started using the CocoaPods, and I have never had any problem before.

My `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase', '= 2.5.0'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
pod 'Google'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'XLForm', '~> 3.0'

target 'Dimmi' do

end

target 'DimmiTests' do

end

target 'DimmiUITests' do

end
```

The XLForm library does not depends on any other library or framework. Also, I tried to install it manually with no success.

Comment: You should consider using Eureka, as that is the Swift version of XLForms.

Comment: Actually I had a worse problem with Eureka, as soon as I added it to my project it did not compile anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a bridging header file and import the Objective-C framework through it.

Create a new header file and name it in the following pattern:

```
ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h
```

Then add your framework header to it

```
#import Framework.h
```

Then add the bridging header to your build settings under `Objective-C Bridging Header`.